# location for build jar or war for gradle

Tags: java, gradle

i have success using gradle build

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

but when i need the war or jar it is not ready yet in my Folder. i want to know where is the default location of the jar or war if i use gradle...

i have set like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'fa.il.ick'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

look  under the **$project/build/libs/** folder